# Passing arguments to input file for beamer title page

Tags: beamer, titles, input

I am looking for ways to pass a text to a file used to create the title page in beamer presentations. I use a file `BeamerTitle.tex` for different classes.

I would like to send the "Class Topic" as an input argument to the BeamerTitle.tex file in `\input{BeamerTitle}`. How can I do this?

Thank you!

The MWE is below.

`BeamerTitle.tex`

```
\title[Running Title]{\LARGE{\textbf{Title of the Course}}}

\author[Running Instructor]{%
    \textbf{Instructor Name}
    \vspace{2\baselineskip} \\
    {\Large Class Topic (as input, with same color as title)}
    \vspace{5\baselineskip} \\
    Univ info line 1 \\
    Univ info line 2 \\
    \ \\
    Semester}
\date{}
    
\begin{frame}
        \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

`MainFile.tex`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Title on PDF properties},
    pdfauthor={Author on PDF properties},
    pdfsubject={Subject on PDF properties}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{centering}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \text{\strut\insertframetitle}  % \strut to fix height of title.
    \par
\end{centering}
}

\begin{document}

\input{BeamerTitle} % Should pass parameter "Class Topic"

\section{Topic of the Class}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Topic of the Class}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Etc
        \item Etc
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Etc
            \item Etc
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Title page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your class topic in a macro:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Title on PDF properties},
    pdfauthor={Author on PDF properties},
    pdfsubject={Subject on PDF properties}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{centering}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \text{\strut\insertframetitle}  % \strut to fix height of title.
    \par
\end{centering}
}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{BeamerTitle.tex}
\title[Running Title]{\LARGE{\textbf{Title of the Course}}}

\author[Running Instructor]{%
    \textbf{Instructor Name}
    \vspace{2\baselineskip} \\
    {\Large \classtopic}
    \vspace{5\baselineskip} \\
    Univ info line 1 \\
    Univ info line 2 \\
    \ \\
    Semester}
\date{}
    
\begin{frame}
        \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\classtopic}{
Class Topic (as input, with same color as title)
}

\begin{document}

\input{BeamerTitle} % Should pass parameter "Class Topic"

\section{Topic of the Class}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Topic of the Class}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Etc
        \item Etc
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Etc
            \item Etc
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to store the class topic in a macro. I will then accept your answer, as I use it. However, I made some additional changes to the method below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution. I store the class topic as a macro that is used later in the tex file. But the whole point is that now I define the elements of the title page separately and use the elements with more flexibility. In this way, I can use the class topic and other elements with the same colors of the beamer theme.

Also, as the title elements are defined in the preamble, they do not conflict with the `hyperref` package.

Main file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Course title}
\subtitle{Subtitle name}
\author{Instructor name}
\institute{Institute name}
\date{Course date}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Title on PDF properties},
    pdfauthor={Author on PDF properties},
    pdfsubject={Subject on PDF properties}
}

% Class topic in title page
\newcommand{\ClassTopic}{Class Topic}

\begin{document}

\input{BeamerTitle02.tex}

\end{document}
```

Title file (`BeamerTitle02.tex`):

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
    \vskip0.25em%
    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
    \fi%     
\end{beamercolorbox}%

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{author}
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}

{\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}{\ClassTopic}\par
\end{beamercolorbox}

\begin{center}
\insertinstitute

\insertdate
\end{center}

\end{frame}
```

[image: Title page]